# Different Controller not running.. Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, controller

I am working on the codeigniter framework to make a cms.During development i.e. running the site on my localhost i had two controllers and both worked fine.But now that I have uploaded it to a server it doesnt run the second Controller..
Someone having any idea regarding this please help!!

Comment: Just shows a blank page when the existing controller redirects to the second controller

Comment: It will be appreciated if you can please accept this answer, if it has worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

If your page shows blank page then there might be possibility of php code error

Please try with enabling error reporting on from your index.php at the top level by following code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

If there is any code error, it will display you error with detail

Hope this will help you